# Is there a way to merge multiple update queries into one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to update the description information for each province code in Provinces table. What I am doing is:

```
update Provinces
set Description='Mississippi'
where Code = 'MS'

update Provinces
set Description = 'Maryland'
where Code = 'MD'

.... --around 100 more update queries like that.
```

In this way, there is a repeated lines of code, which does not look good to me. I wonder if there is any better and more professional way to do the same task. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
update Provinces
set Description= CASE code WHEN 'MS' THEN 'Mississippi'
                           WHEN 'MD' THEN 'Maryland' 
                           -- ELSE 'some default value' --otherwise NULL
                 END
where Code IN('MS', 'MD');
```

---

Another approach is to create table variable and use `UPDATE FROM JOIN` syntax:

```
DECLARE @t AS (code VARCHAR(10), desc VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @t(code, desc) VALUES ('MS','Mississippi'), ('MD', 'Maryland');

UPDATE p
SET desc = t.desc
FROM Provinces p
JOIN @t t
  ON p.Code = t.code;
```

Comment: What does the WHERE clause in the first option, the CASE query, actually do? It seems redundant?

Comment: @l008com If you don't define WHERE condition then you have to handle other scenarios. For instance for Code = 'CA' you have provide some value or set to itself  `ELSE Description`. It seems all right, but there is no point of making identity transformation. Second perfromance if your table has 1mln rows, MS/MD has both around 20k rows, what is the point of updating rest of 980k rows 1:1.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to using `case` expression is to use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) and join to the `cte` like so:

```
;with ProvinceDescription as (
  select Description, Code
  from (values 
      ('Mississippi','MS')
     ,('Maryland','MD')
    ) v (Description, Code)
)
update p
  set p.Description = pd.Description
from Provinces p
  inner join ProvinceDescription pd
    on p.Code = pd.Code
where p.Description <> pd.Description;
```

Comment: Or skip the CTE and just `inner join ( values ( 'Mississippi', 'MS' ), ( 'Maryland', 'MD' ) ) as ProvinceDescription ( Description, Code ) on ProvinceDescription.Code = p.Code`.

Comment: @Habo True, I just prefer the cte as I think it increases readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your unique constrains set up properly, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO Provinces (Description, Code)
VALUES ('Maryland', 'MD'), ('Mississippi', 'MS')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Description=VALUES(Description), Code=VALUES(Code)
```

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server` != `MySQL` Also it doesn't solve OP case.